# Rails 5 Active Record - Query that determines if sibling record exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

The software I'm building helps plan events and contact people to attend events. We want to identify all Users who we have not yet invited to a specific event via a `PhoneCall`. To do this we want to query:

1) All Users for whom no `ContactAttempt` for any event exists

2) Users who for whom no `ContactAttempt` with event_id = this event.id and this attempted_type = `PhoneCall`. (this captures those who we contacted via a `Text` but not a `PhoneCall`)

```
User.includes(:contact_attempts).references(:contact_attempts)
.where('contact_attempts.id IS NULL OR (contact_attempts.event_id = ? AND contact_attempts.attempted_type != ?)', @event.id, "PhoneCall")
```

**But this query leaves out third group of Users I want to target, who I have been unable to include in the query:**

The `Users` who have a `ContactAttempt` for a different event_id, but not for this event_id. At first I thought it could be done with `contact_attempts.event_id != ?`, but that included all Users who had an existing `ContactAttempt` **even if they have been contacted for this event_id**,

How can I construct the query to also target all Users who have no `ContactAttempt` for this particular event with attempted_type = `PhoneCall`, but may have a `ContactAttempt` for a previous event?

Is this something that requires Arel?

Comment: For the model associations: does `user` `has_many` `contact_attempts` and does `contact_attempt` `belongs_to` `users`?

Answer (score 1):

```
User.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN contact_attempts 
            ON contact_attempts.user_id = users.id')
    .where('contact_attempts.id IS NULL 
            OR (contact_attempts.event_id = ?
            AND contact_attempts.attempted_type != ?)',
            @event.id, "PhoneCall")
```

I think the issue with the includes and references is it won't get users without the association, where as left join will return users both with and without contact attempts